# Getting Objects out of OrderedDict in Python to be altered

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, deep-copy, ordereddictionary

I am trying to use a dictionary to prevent myself from storing duplicates and that works fine but then when I try to get the objects out of the dictionary and call functions on them the interpreter tells me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ejsol/Desktop/NflData/playerDataCollector.py", line 24, in         
<module>
print unique_qb[0].stats(2015, week=13)
TypeError: 'OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

I tried making deep copies of the elements in the dictionary and using those to make a list but I am still getting the same issue. I read some information about how python binds names to objects so that is why I thought that copying the objects out of the dictionary would work but it appears not to be working.

Heres my code:

```
import nflgame
import copy

players = dict()
qbs = dict()
#get a list of all games in 2014
games = nflgame.games(2014)
#make a list of the players in each game
for g in games:
    _p = g.players
    for p in _p:
        if p.playerid not in players:
            players[p.playerid] = p
#find all the qbs in the players
for p in players:
    if players[p].guess_position == 'QB' and p not in qbs:
        qbs[p] = players[p]
    #copy qbs to a list that I can manipulate
    unique_qb = []
    for v in qbs:
        c = copy.deepcopy(qbs[v])
        unique_qb.append(c)
    print unique_qb[0].name
    print unique_qb[0].stats(2015, week=13)#this line produces the error
```

How can I get objects out of a dictionary to be used without the constraint of being in an ordered dictionary and therefore being "not callable"

edit:

the function

```
unique_qb[0].stats(2015, week=13)
```

is a call to the object that is stored in that entry of the dictionary and here is its stub from the nflgame api I'm trying to use.

```
def stats(self, year, week=None):
    games = nflgame.games(year, week)
    players = list(nflgame.combine(games).filter(playerid=self.playerid))
    if len(players) == 0:
        return GamePlayerStats(self.player_id, self.gsis_name,
                               None, self.team)
    return players[0]
```

Comment: There are no uses of `OrderedDict` here. Which makes me a little suspicious that you have no idea what you're doing, or that your example is omitting very important pieces.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing I am not familiar with python at all. And I didn't think i was using OrderedDict either but the error message told me I was.

Comment: You're indentation in the posted code is wrong.  I get `IndexError: list index out of range` on the `print unique_qb[0].name` line, but I can reproduce your error by unindenting `#copy qbs...` and everything after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is accessed with `[]` not `()`.  The latter is for function calls.

Using a debugger, `.stats` is a property that returns an OrderedDict:

```
@property
def stats(self):
    """
    Returns a dict of all stats for the player.
    """
    return self._stats

[Dbg]>>> unique_qb[0].stats
OrderedDict([(u'passing_att', 33), (u'passing_twoptm', 0), (u'passing_twopta', 0), (u'passing_yds', 250), (u'passing_cmp', 22), (u'passing_ints', 0), (u'passing_tds', 2), (u'rushing_lngtd', 0), (u'rushing_tds', 0), (u'rushing_twopta', 0), (u'rushing_lng', -1), (u'rushing_yds', -1), (u'rushing_att', 1), (u'rushing_twoptm', 0)])
```

Since it is a dictionary, you need `[]`.  For example:

```
[Dbg]>>> unique_qb[0].stats['passing_att']
33
```

Since you described a different function, you're not calling the function you think you are.

Comment: I did access the dictionary with [] ?

Comment: @esoler, As I said, there isn't enough information, but that error message is from calling a dictionary `()` rather than using `[]`.  Post the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense thanks for you're answer. Hey what debugger did you use to get that information? I'm only familiar with c++ / c# / java and use vs or intelij so I dont really know what the good stuff to use for python is. I probably wouldn't have had to waste your time if I knew where to start debugging. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @esoler, I used `PythonWin` from the `pywin32` module, but `Idle` comes with Python and has a source debugger as well.